# How to publish on user's wall with C# Facebook SDK 6.0.10.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

It's hard to find documentation for the newest SDK. I have an app that users signed in agreeing to giving permission for the app to post on their wall.

Now I have the app's access token and I'd like to post and entry on the user's wall. Seems like a simple operation but I can't find any examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [FaceBook C# SDK](http://csharpsdk.org/). Here's [an article](http://blog.yaplex.com/facebook/facebook-c-sdk-how-to-post-on-wall/) which illustrates how you could post on a user's wall:

```
dynamic messagePost = new ExpandoObject();
messagePost.picture = "http://yaplex.com/uploads/yaplex-logo-with-text-small.png";
messagePost.link = "http://yaplex.com/";
messagePost.name = "[name] Facebook name...";

// "{*actor*} " + "posted news..."; //<---{*actor*} is the user (i.e.: Alex)
messagePost.caption = " Facebook caption";
messagePost.description = "[description] Facebook description...";
messagePost.message = "[message] Facebook message...";

string acccessToken = "xxxx5120330xxxx|4xxxxx0c0f95bd3f62dxxxxx.1-10000xx4x73xxxx|2xx5xxx0566xxxx|z2xxxx37dxxxxsdDS23s_Sah34a";
FacebookClient appp = new FacebookClient(acccessToken);
try
{
    var postId = appp.Post("24351740xxxxxx" + "/feed", messagePost);
}
catch (FacebookOAuthException ex)
{
    //handle oauth exception
}
catch (FacebookApiException ex)
{
    //handle facebook exception
}
```